# Difference between hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size and batch fetch strategy @BatchSize

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, configuration, batch-fetching

For the N+1 queries issue in Hibernate, I add `@BatchSize(size=20)` on collection and class level. And it works very well as it fetches 20 records each time.
Now I found that there is a `hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size` configuration option which I think it is the same as `@BatchSize` annotation.
However, it has no effect to the N+1 queries issue when I configured it in my project.

Am I wrong with `hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size` ?
What is `hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size` for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size` is a [JDBC driver configuration](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/jboss_enterprise_application_platform/5/html/performance_tuning_guide/sect-performance_tuning_guide-entity_beans-batching_database_operations), and it determines:

> the number of rows fetched when there is more than a one row result on
> select statements

Hibernate uses this configuration to set the [PreparedStatement.fetchSize](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setFetchSize(int)) and according to JDBC documentation:

> Gives the JDBC driver a hint as to the number of rows that should be
> fetched from the database when more rows are needed for ResultSet
> objects genrated by this Statement. If the value specified is zero,
> then the hint is ignored. The default value is zero.

So this setting is only a hint and it allows the JDBC Driver to retrieve the selected rows in batches, to minimize the number of database network round-trips.

The `@BatchSize` is a [Hibernate fetching](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-the-importance-of-fetch-strategy/) optimization and it controls the number of SELECT statements being generated.