# Difference between fetch_size and page_size in JDBC input

Tags: java, jdbc, logstash-jdbc

I'm using Logstash to import a lot of data from a MySQL database. I'm facing a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` error.
After a few searches I found out a good solution is to enable paging ([here](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-jdbc/issues/9)) and set `jdbc_page_size`.

In the current conf I use, the `jdbc_fetch_size` is already set.

Now, my questions are:

- What are the differences between those two parameters?
- Do they interact? In a opposite or similar way?

The info I gathered so far are:

- [this topic](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/jdbc-fetch-size-vs-jdbc-page-size/168530) asking if :

> jdbc_page_size determines the number of rows that are fetched from database per trip

- And [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28757257/difference-between-hibernate-jdbc-fetch-size-and-batch-fetch-strategy-batchsize), about hibernate, stating that:

> `hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size` determines the number of rows fetched when there is more than a one row result on select statements

And of course [logstash doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html#plugins-inputs-jdbc-jdbc_fetch_size)

Can anyone clarify it?